How to trigger a click event on a parent div excluding a specific child element in Angular?
I have an Angular component with nested div elements. I want to trigger a click event on the parent div, but if the menu child div is clicked, the parent div's click event should not be triggered.
Demo@StackBlitz
main.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div (click)="openAlert()" class="parent">Parent
      <div class="menu">Menu</div>
      <div class="child child-2">Child 2</div>
      <div class="child child-3">Child 3</div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  public openAlert() {
    alert('Details View');
  }
}


I don't use images just text and a menu icon. Click event should not be triggered, when clicking on the menu icon.

I'm really sorry, I commented on the wrong question, I have posted an answer below. Happy coding :)

You can use event.stopPropagation() in the click event handler for the "menu" div. This method stops the event will propagating to the parent element.
Here is how you can update your code:


import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div (click)="openAlert()" class="parent">Parent
      <div (click)="stopPropagation($event)" class="menu">Menu</div>
      <div class="child child-2">Child 2</div>
      <div class="child child-3">Child 3</div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  public openAlert() {
    alert('Details View');
  }

  public stopPropagation(event: MouseEvent) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}




the child events are bubbling, check this stackblitz please update the same on your answer, nice answer!

hi @NarenMurali, I think he wants to stopPropagation only if the menu is clicked (not if other children are). But yeah he would have to update to your version if he wants to stopPropagation on all children (or wrap them in another div and use the click only once). Thank you

Inside your click handler function you can inspect the click event's target and detect whether the click was from within the parent div and not a child div. I put a menu-wrapper around the child divs to simplify your example.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div class="parent" (click)="onClick($event)">
      Parent
      <div class="menu-container">
        <div class="menu">Menu</div>
        <div class="child child-2">Child 2</div>
        <div class="child child-3">Child 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App  {
  name = 'Angular';

  protected onClick(ev: MouseEvent): void {
    // if within parent div but not within menu-container div
    const shouldShowAlert =
    ev.target instanceof HTMLElement && !!ev.target.closest('.parent') && !ev.target.closest('.menu-container')

    if (shouldShowAlert) {
      this.openAlert();
    }
  }

  public openAlert() {
    alert('Details View');
  }
}

More information about the closest method can be found here.
